# How do I create a Boilerplate Airflow DAG that I can inherit from

Tags: airflow, python-3.10

I know how to dynamically generate dags but also wanted to create a boilerplate DAG that other DAGs can inherit from.

Below generates the first dag but it doesn't inherit e.g. the default_args nor any of the tasks (including those in the subclass)

ps. im on airflow version 2.5.1

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


class BaseDag(DAG):
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 18),
        'schedule_interval': None,
    }

    def __init__(self, dag_id):
        super().__init__(
            dag_id=dag_id,
            default_args=self.default_args,
            catchup=False
        )

    def create_dag(self):
        with self:
            start = EmptyOperator(task_id='start')
            end = EmptyOperator(task_id='end')

            # Define your DAG structure here

            start >> end


class MyDag(BaseDag):
    def create_dag(self):
        super().create_dag()

        # Add your specific tasks and dependencies here

        task1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='run_after_loop',
            bash_command='echo 1',
        )
        task2 = BashOperator(
            task_id='run_after_loop',
            bash_command='echo 1',
        )
        task3 = BashOperator(
            task_id='run_after_loop',
            bash_command='echo 1',
        )

        start = self.get_task('start')
        end = self.get_task('end')

        start >> task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> end


first_dag = MyDag(dag_id='first_dag')
```